# How to get X and Y coordinates of a signature drawn in a bitmap canvas

Tags: android

Given below is my Java code.  I want to capture the signature drawn in the bitmap and store it in a string array (X and Y coordinates of the signature).

```
package com.ust.mobile.android.jnj;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class SignatureFieldClass extends View{


    private int nBitmapWidth = 700;
    private int nBitmapHeight = 220;

    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private ArrayList<String> signature=new ArrayList<String>();
    public SignatureFieldClass(Context c) {
        super(c);

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4); 

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(nBitmapWidth, nBitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFF6386AD);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }



    public void ClearPath(){
         mPath.reset();
         invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Do you just need to get the (x, y) coordinates of the signature, or are you trying read the person's name?  How does your code work, and what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: hey i need to get the (x, y) coordinates of the signature...help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can store the X and Y coordinates of the bitmap to a string array.for dat we can use below code.
 private int mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

```
private void touch_start(int  x, int y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    s=Integer.toString(mX);
    //signatures=s;
    sb.append(s);
    sb.append(",");
    //signature[0]=s;
    mY = y;
    s=Integer.toString(mY);
    sb.append(s);

    //signature[1]=s;
}
private void touch_move(int x, int y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        s=Integer.toString(mX);
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append(",");
       /* int l=signature.length;
        signature[l]=s;*/
        mY = y;
        s=Integer.toString(mY);
        sb.append(s);

         /*l=signature.length;
         signature[l]=s;*/
    }
}
private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    s=Integer.toString(mX);
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append(s);
    s=Integer.toString(mY);
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append(s);
    sb.append(",");
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is not full code.it s d part f code dat captures x and y coordinates.sb is a string buffer.we can copy d values in d string buffer to a string.

Comment: Hi Seethalakshmi..Is this code will work for all devices..I mean tab ,mobile,,x,y coordinates will be same for both tab and mobile device. kindly let me know check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758064/how-to-get-the-co-ordinates-of-the-imageview-irrespective-of-the-device