# Draw Bitmap in Custom ImageView and get the Co-ordinates of the ImageView irrespective of the device

Tags: android, canvas, coordinates, draw, android-custom-view

I want to get the co-ordinates of the `ImageView`, Irrespective of device size.

Is there any possible way !!

I have tried to create specific size for the `ImageView`,Even specific size for the `Parent View` also ,but its not working.

I have tried the following possible ways.

```
int[] posXY = new int[2];
imageview.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
int MoveX = posXY[0];
int MoveY = posXY[1];
```

I have tried with Matrix too ,But not working.

```
Matrix m = imageview.getImageMatrix();
```

Tried the below code, but it is also not working.!!

I need to get the same {x,y} Co-ordinates for all devices for the same point (Location).

```
final float[] getPointerCoords(ImageView view, MotionEvent e)
    {
        final int index = e.getActionIndex();
        final float[] coords = new float[] { 
                e.getX(index), e.getY(index) 
                };
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        view.getImageMatrix().invert(matrix);

        matrix.mapPoints(coords);

        return coords;
    }
```

Here is draw Method :

if i set bitmap image in draw, it does not fit the screen for every devices. If i set image with Display width and height, i am getting different co-ordinates.

```
 @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.draw(canvas);

        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.subimage);
        mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();     
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }
```

Any Idea or help would be really helpful.

Comment: In which method did you call `imageview.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);`?

Comment: use `getImageMatrix` and read **carefully** `Matrix` API

Comment: @pskink hi,kindly check my updated question

Comment: did you read the `Canvas` API ?

Comment: @pskink i have not tried with canvas onDraw method,Let me try !!

Comment: @pskink i have tried Canvas too canvas.getClipBounds() but its not working

Comment: clip bounds have nothing to do here, as i said use the transformation `Matrix`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90584/discussion-between-janmejoy-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink i have tried with Transformation matrix with  matrix.postTranslate seems no change

Comment: `Log.d` the value of that matrix in `onDraw` method, it should help you understand how it works, from the docs: `"Return the view's optional matrix. This is applied to the view's drawable when it is drawn"`

Comment: Yes ,!! we can get the value when its drawn only..But how could we get the co-ordinates,when you tap on the screen

Comment: then override `onTouchEvent` and use that `Matrix` there

Comment: @pskink its not working

Comment: yes it is working, read the `Matrix` API

Comment: @pskink how could you pass the matrix in onTouch event

Comment: you dont pass, you just call `getImageMatrix`

Comment: Okay getImageMatrix of the View,The method getImageMatrix() is undefined for the type View

Comment: we are talking about custom `ImageView`, aren't we? `"How to get the Co-ordinates of the ImageView irrespective of the device"`

Comment: @pskink exactly..and its not working

Comment: @pskink it is not working shows only x value and its not changing also

Comment: @pskink kindly check my updated question

Comment: why do you call postTranlate?

Comment: @pskink kindly check the updated question ,Still not working

Comment: the code is ok,  what does not work?

Comment: @pskink I am getting different co-ordinates,In Nexus Tab I am getting different (x,y) values,where as in Samsung mobile i am getting different(x,y) values for same location.

Comment: click on top left corner of your image,  you shoud get 0, 0

Comment: @pskink No,I am not getting 0,0

Comment: MotionEvent e,  is it from ImageVuew?  if not it will not work

Comment: @pskink MotionEvent is calling from Activity but it is implemented in custom Imageview

Comment: @pskink here is the custom view http://pastie.org/10443302

Comment: see http://codeshare.io/xxjSB: click left-top corner of the red rectangle and you will have coords [0..1][0..1] and bottom-right corner and you will get [19..20][19..20] because the size of the Drawable is 20x20

Comment: @pskink thanks but what if the image is custom image taken  from drawable..do we have any solution for that

Comment: @pskink still i am not getting the same coordinates ,it gets differ in mobile as well as tab

Comment: did you run my code? did you get [0,0] and [19,19] in both corners (left-top and bottom-right)?

Comment: @pskink yeah its working !! because you have assigned customize width and height ,How about if the image size is not assigned

Comment: image size not assigned? so image with size 0x0 ? it means width == 0 and height == 0, then no image will be drawn

Comment: @pskink if i add the image like that  Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
        setImageDrawable(drawable);

Comment: @pskink then its not working!!

Comment: setImageDrawable is not working? it is working for me

Comment: @pskink please try this http://pastie.org/10447690 and let me know if its working for you or not

Comment: read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence)

Comment: @pskink we need to change the image size according to density hope so..

Comment: no, you have to place it in a right drawable folder, more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Comment: @pskink exactly let me try with this

Comment: @pskink No still not working...I have created (xhdpi - 720*1280) ,then 320*480 ,480*800 but seems its also not working

Comment: have you read the link i posted? have you seen `Table 1` ?  if so, have you read about **ALL** `*dpi` qualifiers?

Comment: @pskink Thanks my friend found the solution finally

Comment: and what was it? what was the solution?

Comment: @pskink i put the images in seperate drawable folder ,It works

Comment: what separate? seems you choose wrong solution...

Comment: @pskink change image size and added to different drawable folder,like mdpi,hpdi,it works

Comment: @pskink still i am looking for some better solution

Comment: ok, nodpi is your solution

Comment: @pskink thats also right anyway Thanks friend..I am trying to do something programatically

Comment: @pskink Question has been updated kindly check

Comment: so what is `void draw(Canvas canvas)` for?

Comment: @pskink i want to draw line over the co-ordinates..That is why i am using draw

Comment: sorry, have no idea whats your point, what line? i see you want to draw some bitmap

Comment: @pskink I will get some co-ordinates right..one point {x1,y1} and some other point {x2,y2} ,I need to draw line   canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, mPaint);

Comment: so what do you need pixel cooords for? just use MotionEvent#getX() / getY() and draw the line

Comment: @pskink yeah i got the co-ordinates but while i draw bitmap using canvas it does not fit the screen,If i make it customize ,i lose the co-ordinates

Comment: just use MotionEvent#getX / MotionEvent#getY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found some relative solution,Same Co-ordinates for all devices.Using Activity,no Custom ImageView.

On ImageView OnTouch ..

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
      final int index = e.getActionIndex();
      final float[] coords = new float[] {
              e.getX(index), e.getY(index)
      };
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      choosenImageView.getImageMatrix().invert(matrix);
      matrix.mapPoints(coords);
    return true;
  }
```

Draw Using Canvas

```
        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image);

        Bitmap bmp= ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

        alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
        canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        matrix = new Matrix();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate your device screen ratio first,

```
deviceWidth / screenHeight = ratio
```

then you have to multiply it with your desired coordinate :

```
ratio * xCoord = newXcoord; // and same for Y coord
```

By doing this you will keep the equivalent coordinates for all device sizes.

Also you may declare sizes and coordinates with respect to % of screen dimensions like :

```
x = 0.2 * deviceWidth  // %20 of device width from left
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
imageview.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int[] posXY = new int[2];
                imageview.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
                int MoveX = posXY[0];
                int MoveY = posXY[1];
Log.i("xy co-ordinate", "x "+MoveX, "y"+MoveY);

            }
        });
```